# component not rendering when using react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

There are many answers to this question, but they only answer about either they are missing or forgot to replace any keywords such as `exact`, `Redirect` etc., or the flow of code.

Recently I have upgraded my react app from `react-router-dom: "^5.2.0"` to `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`. I have followed the [Migrate to v6 from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6) guide and I am not able to see components rendering on particular routes. As part of only `react-router-dom`, I am only adding `routes` part of the React `app` and `component`. The way I followed the migration guide is as below:

**index.js**

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');

// Create a root.
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <Provider store={Store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App: FunctionComponent<IAppProps> = () => {

    /* other stuff useEffect and fetch functions etc... */

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ResetStyles />
            <Routes>
                {/* Public Facing */}
                <Route path="*" element={<ViewLogin />} />
                <Route path="/forgotten-password/*" element={<ViewForgottenPassword />} />        
                <Route path="/user/signup" element={<ViewUserSignup />} />

                {/* User Protected */}
                <Route path="/account-selection/" element={<ViewAccountSelection />} />
                <Route path="/sign-out" element={<ViewSignOut />} />
                <Route path="/user" element={<ViewUserConfiguration />} />
                <Route path="/404" element={<ViewError404 />} />
                <Route path="/:account/" element={<ViewDashboard />} />

                {/* Error Pages */}
                <Route element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />
            </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**dashboard.tsx**

```
const ViewDashboard = (props: any) => {

   /* other stuff useEffect and fetch functions etc... */

   return (
        <div className="dashboard-container">
            <Nav showSidebar={showSidebar} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />

            <div className={showSidebar ? 'dashboard-view-expanded' : 'dashboard-view-collapsed'}>
                <ViewMenu sidebarExpanded={showSidebar} history={props.history} upperMenuTitle={getTitle()} />
                <div className="dashboard-view__content">
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/:account/" element={<Navigate to={`${account.token}/reports/dashboard`} />} />
                        <Route path="/:account/account-management/*" element={<LayoutAccountManagement />} />
                        <Route path="/:account/reports/" element={<LayoutReport />} />
                        <Route element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />
                    </Routes>
                </div>
                <ViewModal />
                <ViewNotification />
                <ViewPopup />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(ViewDashboard, isEqual);
```

`render` method of **account-selection.js**

```
render() {
        if (this.props.user.isLoggedIn !== true) {
            return <Navigate push to="/" />;
        } else if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return <ViewLoadingSplash />;
        } else if (this.state.hasAccount || this.props.account.isSelected) {
            console.log('Gone through account selection');
            this.props.setDisplayMenu(true);
            return <Navigate push to={`/${this.props.account.token}`} />;
        }

        return (
            <div id="account-selection__view">
                <div className="account-selection__content">
                    <div className="account-selection__content__selection">
                        <h3>Select Account</h3>
                        <ComponentInputField
                            value={this.state.search}
                            onChange={this.onInputChange}
                            placeholder="Search accounts..."
                            type="text"
                        />
                        <ComponentList rows={this.state.visibleAccounts} onRowClick={this.onAccountClick} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ViewNotifications />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Now the app flow is, on login, there is an account selection page where I select users and it will take me to their dashboard.

If everything is working correctly we should see the following route and the user's dashboard:

`http://localhost:3000/demoUser/reports/dashboard`

Instead, it is taking me to `http://localhost:3000/demoUser` with no dashboard view at all.

Not sure where it is going wrong or if I am missing something huge in this. A proper way of doing this would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no route matching/rendering on `"/demoUser"`. The closest matches are either `"*"` rendering `ViewLogin`, or `"/:account/*"` rendering `ViewDashboard`. I think it's the latter, which then possibly redirects to `${account.token}/reports/dashboard` ***or*** `:account/${account.token}/reports/dashboard` depending on the value of `account.token`. But then there's no route rendering a matching path for this. The next closest path is the descendent `"/:account/reports"` route rendering `LayoutReport`.  Please confirm what this value is.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I have edited the `dashboard.tsx` routes by comparing the original code base. Basically the first sequence is correct, after verifying a user is exist and is valid, it redirects to `${account.token}/reports/dashboard`. But not sure what exactly you mean by confirming the value.

Comment: Confirm the value, i.e. `console.log(account.token)`. What is the value you are using to create a target path? What is the computed path value versus what you expect it to be?

Comment: So, on `console.log` I can see the username which I have saved in my DB. the same username in route as well, that is `demoUser`.

Comment: So where is the user, what path/URL/etc when you thing the path should navigate to `"/demoUser/reports/dashboard"`? In other words, what are the steps to take to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The user comes after `login` which is on route `/*` and then `/account-selection`. If you see this line `return <Navigate push to={'/${this.props.account.token}'} />` in `render` method of `account-selection.js` is responsible for redirecting to `/userDemo/reports/dashboard`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247301/discussion-between-trojanatwar-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues I see are the `Routes` components are rendering routes with paths without a trailing `"*"` wildcard character to allow descendent route path matching. From what I can see you want the user to navigate to `"/account-selection"` and render the `ViewAccountSelection` component which under the correct conditions will navigate the user to `"/demoUser"`, i.e. the `"/:account"` route renders `ViewDashboard` component. The `ViewDashboard` then navigates the user to `"/demoUser/reports/dashboard"` to render the `LayoutReport` component.

Add the missing wildcard path characters to the routes that need it.

App

```
<Routes>
  {/* Public Facing */}
  <Route path="*" element={<ViewLogin />} />
  <Route
    path="/forgotten-password/*"
    element={<ViewForgottenPassword />}
  />
  <Route path="/user/signup" element={<ViewUserSignup />} />

  {/* User Protected */}
  <Route
    path="/account-selection/"
    element={
      <ViewAccountSelection
        account={account}
        user={{ isLoggedIn: true }}
      />
    }
  />
  <Route path="/sign-out" element={<ViewSignOut />} />
  <Route path="/user" element={<ViewUserConfiguration />} />
  <Route path="/404" element={<ViewError404 />} />
  <Route path="/:account/*" element={<ViewDashboard />} /> // <-- here

  {/* Error Pages */}
  <Route element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />
</Routes>
```

ViewDashboard

```
const ViewDashboard = () => (
  <div className="dashboard-container">
    ...
      <div className="dashboard-view__content">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            index // <-- index route, i.e. "/:account"
            element={<Navigate to="reports/dashboard" />} // <-- navigate relative
          />
          <Route
            path="/account-management/*"
            element={<LayoutAccountManagement />}
          />
          <Route path="/reports/*" element={<LayoutReport />} /> // <-- add trailing *
          <Route element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit component-not-rendering-when-using-react-router-dom-v6]